# Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'String'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'String'. [angular]

Tags: angular

im trying to affect a set Attribute from class.ts with a variable in my component.ts ( angular ) like this :

```
this.UserPaiemet.setDate(this.DateN)
```

The IDE shows me this errors :

```
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'String'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'String'.

131     this.UserPaiemet.setDate(this.DateN)
```

i don't know how can i fix it .

My class:

```
export class UserPaiemet
{
 private id!:Number;
 private date!:String;
 private nbrmois!:Number;
}
```

**ANd my component Method**

```
date = new Date()
  DateN  = this.datePipe.transform(this.date, "yyyy-MM-dd")
  UserPaiemet= new UserPaiemet()
  updateUserPai()
  {
  this.UserPaiemet.setDate(this.DateN)
  }
```

Comment: Can you include the `this.dataPipe` code? TypeScript is complaining that that might return `null`, and then you can't pass that into `setDate`.

Comment: it's a pipe library from angular , i  declare it in the constructor ' private datePipe: DatePipe '

Comment: You just have to handle the possible `null` value coming out of `datePipe.transform`. WIth an `if` for instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following convention for declaring types eg.(String -> string)

```
export class UserPaiemet {
    private id!: number;
    private date!: string;
    private nbrmois!: number;
}
```

---

```
date = new Date();
DateN = this.datePipe.transform(this.date, "yyyy-MM-dd") || ''; // or dummy date here
UserPaiemet = new UserPaiemet();
updateUserPai();
{
    this.UserPaiemet.setDate(this.DateN);
}
```

Comment: Also might be in your case `this.datePipe.transform` is returning null, you will need to handle that

Answer (score 0):

try change your datatypes to lowercase

```
export class UserPaiemet
{
 private id:number;
 private date:string;
 private nbrmois:number;
}
```

Comment: still nothing change

Answer (score 0):

In javascript "number" is the primitive type, "Number" instead is the object type. As a comparison in Java int and Integer (int is primitive type Integer instead is object type) so in your case Number is not equal to number. But in your case the problem is another: you cannot assign null or string to String type. Probably the ide is not recognizing well the object type so try to put it in lower case and execute it.

otherwise try it:

```js
export class UserPaiemet
{
 private id:number;
 private date:string|null;
 private nbrmois:number;
}
```